# Get filename from .torrent in Java

Tags: java, file, bittorrent

How can I get the "real" filename from a file in a .torrent, to print it in java?
I can getFileName and getAbsolutePath, but I want the filename of the actual file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Torrent File Format](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html). It will give you information on how to get file names from the file and the peers.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use a BitTorrent library, such as [Snark](http://www.staging.threerings.net/snark.html), [torrent4j](http://code.google.com/p/torrent4j/), [bitext](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitext/) or [Yaircc](http://yaircc.sourceforge.net/).